# SQL query -- not returning the right data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

In my query I need to return distinct fields for my search.  However the txt_note field returns info even if there is none.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T_ORDER_DETAIL.TXT_ORDER_NUMBER, 
                T_ORDER_DETAIL.CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID, 
                T_VENDOR.VENDOR_ID, 
                T_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.CUSTOMER_ID, 
                T_EMPLOYEE.TXT_EMAIL, 
                T_ORDER_ASSIGNMENT.TXT_NOTE 
FROM   T_VENDOR_EMPLOYEE 
       INNER JOIN T_VENDOR WITH(nolock) 
               ON T_VENDOR_EMPLOYEE.VENDOR_ID = T_VENDOR.VENDOR_ID 
       INNER JOIN T_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT WITH(nolock) 
                  INNER JOIN T_ORDER_DETAIL WITH(nolock) 
                             INNER JOIN T_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT WITH(nolock) 
                                     ON T_ORDER_DETAIL.CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID = 
                                        T_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT.CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID 
                          ON T_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID = 
                             T_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID 
               ON T_VENDOR_EMPLOYEE.VENDOR_EMPLOYEE_ID = 
                  T_ORDER_DETAIL.VENDOR_EMPLOYEE_ID 
       INNER JOIN T_EMPLOYEE WITH(nolock) 
               ON T_VENDOR_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID = T_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID 
       INNER JOIN T_ORDER_DETAIL_REJECTION_REASON WITH(nolock) 
               ON T_ORDER_DETAIL.ORDER_DETAIL_ID = 
                  T_ORDER_DETAIL_REJECTION_REASON.ORDER_DETAIL_ID 
       INNER JOIN T_ORDER_ASSIGNMENT WITH(nolock) 
               ON T_VENDOR_EMPLOYEE.VENDOR_EMPLOYEE_ID = 
                  T_ORDER_ASSIGNMENT.VENDOR_EMPLOYEE_ID 
WHERE  T_ORDER_ASSIGNMENT.INT_ACCEPTED = 4 
       AND T_ORDER_ASSIGNMENT.TXT_NOTE <> ''
```

Even though it returns info, when you look at the actual order that field is blank.

```
txt_Order_Number    Customer_Product_ID vendor_ID   customer_id txt_email   txt_Note
260247648   555 134242  650 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
260498186   2783    134242  429 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
261108453b  1485    134242  206 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
261240252b  4429    134242  206 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
270158583b  4429    134242  206 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
270877727   3190    134242  724 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
271239690b  4817    134242  486 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
280162866b  5378    134242  721 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
280968017b  1485    134242  206 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
290702640   9361    134242  120 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
291294922-50    9972    134242  977 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
300453305-25    3648    134242  206 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
301297011-50    1922    134242  206 jason@propertysmart.us  Out of office
```

only one of the txt_not actually has out of office in it and the rest are blank.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Probably a case where data's not doing what you think it's doing. Return the t_Vendor_Employee.Vendor_Employee_ID column and then look in t_Order_Assignment for that value to ensure the data's correct. Additionally, don't use `with (nolock)` unless you have a very good reason to do so.

Comment: I have done as you suggested and only one of the assignments has the out of office text the rest did not.  I also have to use with (no lock) because hundress of people must access the database at one time.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Why did you tag this both sql server and mysql? And I'm pretty sure with nolock isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: Are you expecting to see _blank_ messages for those orders that don't have a message?  Your `WHERE` clause is specifically **excluding** them, so you may some issues there.  Also, you're `JOIN`ing to `t_Order_Detail_Rejection_Reason`, but do nothing with it - are you expecting all rows to have a rejection (that's the implication)?  I recommend you use table aliasing to shorten your statement (for readability).  If you have sufficient control, I'd also get rid of the `t_` table (and other) prefixes, which are worthless.  And why can `int_Accepted` be `4` - you have four levels of acceptance?

Comment: the t_ is because we have severall table allocations and t_ stands for info table(dont ask).  I have those tables joining that look like they are doing nothing because they are required to search through the tables to find the adjoining int specifiers.  I am excluding items that do not have rejection reasons because that means the items are not rejected.  Company policy prohibits the use of alias (sorry).  t_Order_Assignment.int_Accepted has 4 levels hold, accepted, declined, withdrawn.  Thanks

Comment: Can you describe/show the structure and some contents of t_Order_Assignment and t_Vendor_Employee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try simplifying the query, starting with as few inner joins as possible. Ie:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_Vendor_Employee 
INNER JOIN t_Order_Assignment ON t_Vendor_Employee.vendor_employee_id = t_Order_Assignment.vendor_employee_id 
WHERE t_Order_Assignment.int_Accepted = 4 and t_Order_Assignment.txt_Note <> ''
```

If this gives the expected result, add more inner joins until you get your error - then look at the data and see if you can identify the cause.

---

Also, are you aware that your use of WITH (NOLOCK) might cause you to miss committed rows?

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Has your t_Order_Assignment table column Order_Detail_ID? If yes, add it to ON condition in last join

Comment: +1 - Agreed.  At minimum, he doesn't have enough 'uniqueness' columns used to get different messages for different orders.